# Simplifying a complicated transcendental equation

Tags: numerical-methods, closed-form, transcendental-equations

I want to solve for $x$ the equation

$$ x^{\alpha} (1-x)^{1-\alpha} = (\gamma x)^{\beta} (1-\gamma x)^{1-\beta} $$

where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma, x$ are all strictly between zero and one.

If I'm not mistaken, this is a transcendental equation and an analytic solution may not exist. I however would like to get as close as possible to a closed form solution of the form $x = RHS$.

What assumptions do I need to simplify the problem? Would making $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ rational help?

In case a solution can't be found explicitly, could I still find some way to describe how the $x$ for which the quality holds increases or decreases as a function of the parameters?

Comment: Are you looking for restrictions on the equation so that is has a closed form or a solution to it using sums, integrals, etc?

Comment: If I understand your question: Ideally the latter; however I'm aware it may not be feasible so I'm looking for restrictions that would allow a solution to be found

Comment: For $\alpha=\beta$, we have $x=\frac{\gamma^\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}-1}{\gamma^\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}-\gamma}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer uses $a,b,c$ for MathJax and readability. Rearrange:
$$x^a(1-x)^{1-a}=(cx)^b(1-cx)^{1-b}\iff f(x)=(1-cx)^{b-1}(1-x)^{1-a}x^{a-b}=c^b$$

For $a<b$, $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$is monotonically decreasing and contains $(0,1),(\infty,0)$:

[image]

We apply [Mellin inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem). $g(x)$’s Mellin transform is:

$$\text M_s(g(t))=\int_0^\infty g(t)t^{s-1}dt=\int_0^1t f(t)^{s-1}df(t)$$

Now apply [tabular integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yyic5aaXGaw):

\begin{matrix}&\text D&\text I\\+&t&f(t)^{s-1}f’(t)\\-&1&\frac{f(t)^s}s&\\+&0&\frac1s\int_0^1f(t)^sdt\end{matrix}

so the regularized Gauss hypergeometric function [integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1Regularized/07/01/01/0001/) appears:

$$\text M_s(g(t))=-\frac1s\int_0^1 (1-ct)^{(b-1)s}(1-t)^{(1-a)s}t^{(a-b)s}dt=-\frac{\operatorname B((1-a)s+1,(a-b)s+1)}s\,_2\text F_1((1-b)s,(a-b)s+1;(1-b)s+2;c)$$

Finally, apply the inverse Mellin transform. The solution to the transcendental equation is $g(c^b)$.

$$\bbox[3px,border: 3px #00BFFF ridge]{x^a(1-x)^{1-a}=(cx)^b(1-cx)^{1-b}\implies x=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{d-i\infty}^{d+i\infty}\frac{c^{-sb}}s \operatorname B((1-a)s+1,(a-b)s+1)\,_2 \text F_1((1-b)s,(a-b)s+1;(1-b)s+2;c)ds,a<b}$$

The Mathematica code:
`{FindRoot[x^a(1-x)^(1-a)-(cx)^b(1-cx)^(1-b),{x,1}],1/(2\[Pi] I)NIntegrate[c^(-s b)/s Beta[1+s-a s,1+a s-b s] Hypergeometric2F1[s-b s,1+a s-b s,2+s-b s,c],{s,d-I*p,d+I*p}]}`

verifies the formula for given $a,b,c,p,d$:

[image]

Expanding the beta function and hypergeometric function via [its Mellin-Barnes integral](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/02/0003/), makes it resemble a “[two parameter Fox H function](http://purl.pt/2690/1/j-5293-b-vol31-fasc4-art4_PDF/j-5293-b-vol31-fasc4-art4_PDF_01-B-R0300/j-5293-b-vol31-fasc4-art4_0000_capa1-213_t01-B-R0300.pdf)” which likely gives a “closed form”, but it is not widely accepted as little research on it has been done.

Comment: Thank you, my mind is blown. Lots of this stuff is a little beyond my knowledge so I'll have to take some time to digest, but I'm very grateful for this great answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your first part of the answer (up until Mellin inversion) ensures that for $a<b$ there exists exactly one solution

Comment: @raving-bandit Yes. If $a>b$, then the inverse is not a function and seemingly has 2 branches for the inverse

Comment: I was waiting for this from you ! Cheers :-)